# Increment operator adds two

Tags: node.js

I have the following node.js program:

```
var http = require("http");
var count = 0;

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World: " + yolo());
  response.end();
}).listen(8888);

function yolo(){
     count++;
     return count;
}
```

I run the program in a terminal window and access it through my browser at http://localhost:8888/

I get the following output as I refresh:

- Hello World: 1
- Hello World: 3
- Hello World: 5
- Hello World: 7
- Hello World: 9
- etc...

Why is the program incrementing the count variable by two each time instead of one?

Comment: You sure there isn't another request happening that increments it? Put a `console.log` inside `yolo`

Comment: Most probably there is a request to `favicon.ico`.

Comment: My guess would be that each time you refresh the browser it is issuing two requests to the server. Try logging to a file, including details from the request header like `Date` and `method`.

Comment: @l19 is right. You need to add some logging to see what's going on. This is basic troubleshooting. A single page request can result in multiple additional resource requests. The `favicon` is a resource that the browser asks for automatically.

Comment: @RossPresser Console.log tells me that the function is being called twice. This likely means the browser is sending two requests each time I refresh. Firefox only calls the yolo() function once, as it should. Chrome is the only browser with this problem. Will investigate favicon.ico next. No idea what that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check when the browser makes a call for `/favicon.ico`:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  if (request.url !== '/favicon.ico') {
    response.write("Hello World: " + yolo());
  }
  response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

Comment: The problem is that chrome always makes a request for favicon.ico, even if one doesnt exist. I found its a common complaint after some google-fu. Anyways, this solution works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use a routing library like express to give you what you want.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var count = 0;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  count++;
  res.send('Hello world:'+count);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

This will only respond to requests at "/" instead of every URL like `createServer` will do.